# To close a menu I need to change the direction of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My menu is sliding from right to left on click.

There is an arrow button to open the menu.

To close the menu I need to change the direction of that button.

Please help me with this.

HTML

```
<!-- Menu -->
<nav class="menu" id="theMenu">
    <div class="menu-wrap">
    <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">Menu</a></h1>
    <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>
        <a href="Mywedding.html"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>My Wedding</a>
        <a href="wedding-venue.html">Venue List</a>
        <a href="about-us.html">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

    </div>

    <!-- Menu button -->
    <div id="menuToggle" class=""><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
</nav>
```

JavaScript

```
(function () {
  // Menu settings
  $('#menuToggle, .menu-close').on('click', function () {
    $('#menuToggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('body').toggleClass('body-push-toleft');
    $('#theMenu').toggleClass('menu-open');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: create js fiddle and put your code there

Comment: where is 'arrow button', by the way?

Comment: `<i class="fa fa-angle-left">` this is arrow button @ArtemDudkin

Comment: looks like part of youe code is missing? (i mean css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the class of the fontawesome icons rotation `.fa-rotate-180` adding this line inside your on click function

```
$('#menuToggle').find($(".fa")).toggleClass('fa-rotate-180');
```

You can also add a rotate effect with the css animation

```
#menuToggle i{
    -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}
```